# Do third derivatives commute?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

How does one prove that $$\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\partial_{k} = -\partial_{j}\partial_{i}\partial_{k}?$$

The fact that they permute cyclically follows directly from the symmetry of second derivatives. How and why does this hold? Why aren't third derivatives commutative?

Comment: If you're dealing with $C^3$ functions, then all third order partial derivatives commute; this follows by induction from the symmetry of second partial derivatives. There shouldn't be a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

They are. When your functions are "nice" enough (in this case, for example, $C^3$ or more), third derivatives commute (with no change of any sign). And this easily follows from second derivatives' commutativity (*Schwarz's theorem*). For example:

$$ \partial_j\partial_k f=\partial_k\partial_j f \;\Rightarrow\; \partial_i(\partial_j\partial_k f)=\partial_i(\partial_k\partial_j f) $$

(Note that there's no multiplication, only composition of differential operators.)